# Pocket and RSS Reader. Is there a better way?

Tags: rss, blog, feedly, pocket

I'm a Newsify user (via a lifeboat from Google Reader). I also use Pocket to send things to my feeds to read them later. The problem is that such things turn up like this:

[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

Which is a pain for offline viewing.  (To be clear, it's the words that I'm missing, I could live without the images) Is there a better way? I'm happy to switch from Pocket to a more suitable service... I'd just like things to turn up. I'd be happy with a halfway solution, something that just worked on things that already supported RSS.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of other solutions I'm currently just clipping things into evernote, into a special 'read later' notepad - evernote takes care of the syncing on all devices and everything works wonderfully.

Comment: The state of technology today...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but in case someone else is looking for a solution, it's Poki for Pocket. This app allows you to connect to your pocket account, and then allows you to view your articles saved in pocket offline (minus images). I've been using it for a few days and, so far, it's great. I went looking for it because 1) I've got an upcoming 6 hour plane ride, and 2) I go camping with my laptop alot and have no wifi.

Try it. Poki for Pocket

Comment: It seems like @Joe gave up reading too soon to accept this answer.